# VBA/Excel: How to change cell value if two different terms are met? It also needs recognize when to stop etc

Tags: vba, excel

My problems is following:

I have this kind of table, which I have modified with macros/vba. It contains information as seen in below

[image: original workbook view]

The problem is that I need to recognize the parcel type and then it´s changes the price. Price is connected to the text in parcel type cell and the price is fetch from another workbook (this is not the problem).

What I need to do is:

If region and date are same, then the code should recognize the first trolley/ package and then change the next cell value to Trolley next/Parcel next (the price changes if the text differs from the orginal) until the date and region. changes. This should also be done with all different regions (workbook contains about 20 regions). I have made an example how it should look (See picture 2). Please note the price change is not the problem, it is called from another workbook.

[image: Picture 2: Modified workbook view]

Thanks in advance! Please feel free to ask if you need more information etc

Comment: Please provide solutions you've already tried, where you are running into issues, and an actual question

Comment: Ok, this was just beyond my very poor vba skills, just managed to few basic formations and editings to get data looking like in aa example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, start from the last row and work upwards.

The basic logic here is in pseudo-code:

```
dim row
find last row and assign value to row

for i=row to 1
    if row.B = row-1.B
        if row.C = row-1.C
            add "Next" to end of row.E string
        end if
    end if
    i--
next i
```

This is the full code.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim lastRow As Integer
    
    lastRow = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
    
    Do While lastRow > 1
            
        If Range("B" & lastRow).Value = Range("B" & lastRow - 1).Value Then
            If Range("C" & lastRow).Value = Range("C" & lastRow - 1).Value Then
                Range("E" & lastRow) = Range("E" & lastRow) & " Next"
            End If
        End If
        lastRow = lastRow - 1
    Loop
    
End Sub
```